# Inserting an empty row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This is so simple it has probably already been asked, but I couldn't find it (if that's the case I'm sorry for asking).

I would like to insert an empty row on a table so I can pick up its ID (primary key, generated by an insert trigger) through an ExecuteScalar. Data is added to it at a later time in my code.

My question is this: is there a specific insert syntax to create an empty record? or must I go with the regular insert syntax such as "INSERT INTO table (list all the columns) values (null for every column)"?

Thanks for the answer.

**UPDATE:** In Oracle, ExecuteScalar on INSERT only returns 0. The final answer is a combination of what was posted below. First you need to declare a parameter, and pick up it up with RETURNING.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING ID INTO :parameterName
```

Check this out [link](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server-cs-conversion/insert-returning-clause) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, in order to insert a row where values for all columns are `NULL` except primary

key column's value you could execute a simple `insert` statement:

```
insert into your_table(PK_col_name)
  values(1);                          -- 1 for instance or null
```

The before insert trigger, which is responsible for populating primary key column will

override the value in the `values` clause of the `insert` statement leaving you with an

*empty record* except `PK` value.

Comment: +1 But it might work better to use `DEFAULT` than a hard-coded value.  Then the insert will work regardless of the type, and will also work if the table is changed to use the SYS_GUID() trick or the new 12c sequence default.

Comment: Great! I have combined both answers (insert DEFAULT as value to the PK column) and it works exactly the way I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You would not have to specify every single column, but you may not be able to create an "empty" record. Check for NOT NULL constraints on the table. If none (not including the Primary Key constraint), then you would only need to supply one column. Like this:

```
insert into my_table ( some_column )
values ( null );
```

Do you know about the RETURNING clause? You can return that PK back to your calling application when you do the INSERT.

```
insert into my_table ( some_column )
values ( 'blah' ) 
returning my_table_id into <your_variable>;
```

I would question the approach though. Why create an empty row? That would/could mean there are no constraints on that table, a bad thing if you want good, clean, data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand an empty record might sound like a wrong practice. To make a long story short, I need an empty row so that its ID can be saved in another table at this point in my code. This ID is then used as a reference for other data that the user can save later on, however it is needed when an instance of the class the other table is related to is saved. Thus the need for an empty row.

Comment: So you are saving the data from the dependent table (class) first and need the PK to use as an FK? (Just curious, no need to reply)

Comment: No i was not aware of the `returning` clause,thus *+1* for letting me know,.. :)